# Is the following integral identity true or not?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Is the following statement true or not?$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx = \left. {d\over{dt}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f(x)\,dx\right|_{t = 0}$$

Comment: You posted this question almost identically within the last two days elsewhere. This will not endear you to others.

Comment: Assuming that the LHS exists, equality holds only if $f(x)$ is sufficiently fast-decaying as $|x|\to +\infty$. Otherwise the integral in the RHS might not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is if [Leibnitz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) can be applied to $e^{tx}f(x)$ around $t=0$. Specifically in this case you need an integrable function $\theta$ such that $|xe^{tx}f(x)|\leq \theta(x)$ for $t$ near $0$.